# Send an app request dialog to specific array of id's

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I;m trying to send a request dialog to my friends on facebook but to a few selected ones, i have created an array and i need to send invitation only to the id's on that array, i have this code built but it's not working.

It looks like it stops all my page's performance

```
//function to load friends
function loadFriends()
{
    //get array of friends
    FB.api('/me/friends?fields=name,first_name,gender', function(response) {


        console.log(response);
        var divContainer=$('.facebook-friends');
                         var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");

for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
    if(response.data[i].gender == 'male'){
         testdiv.innerHTML += response.data[i].first_name + response.data[i].id + '<br />';
    }
}

var  arr = []; // Creates an empty array literal.
  for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
    arr.push(response.data[i].id);
  }
  newInvite(arr); // Call your function and pass the friends array

    });
}

function newInvite(arr){
     FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Penelope for WAS',
  filters: ['app_non_users'],
  to:arr.join(',')

});
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your sample code is broken, it misses function closing curly brace and have extra comma (`,`) in the parameter of `FB.ui` (which is ok by standard, but will lead to error in Internet Explorer and your code will not be executed)

Comment: Hi , thanks for replying, in fact i didn't notice much the curly braces, in fact i wanted to know, how am i supposed to send the request just to a selected id's. I have this function in which i extract some id's, then i insert all my id's in an array. in the fb.ui i make that the to parameter to send the request to the array. Will this work?

Comment: Hey, i've edited my code, can yoy please see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use comma separated list as `to` parameter, not an array.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Penelope for WAS',
  filters: ['app_non_users'],
  to:arr.join(',')
});
```

Your code is also have mistake while dealing with JavaScript variable scope.

`newInvite` is a function which missing `arr` variable definition (and `arr` not in global scope, you should pass it to `newInvite` so it'll be available to your function internals.

```
function newInvite(arr){
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Penelope for WAS',
    filters: ['app_non_users'],
    to:arr.join(',')
  });
)
```

And for sure you should pass array of friends ids to the function:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', {fields:'name,first_name,gender'}, function(response) {
  var  arr = []; // Creates an empty array literal.
  for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
    arr.push(response.data[i].id);
  }
  newInvite(arr); // Call your function and pass the friends array
});
```

Comment: it still won't work..
If you go here, in the end of the page there is the invite friends...

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Penelope-Test/411133928921438?sk=app_273511112737682

Comment: If i check it through  the error console, it says that the variable arr is not defined...

Comment: Sure it's not, it's defined in your other function! I've updated the code in answer to outline the issues you have with your code

Comment: Thanks again, i'm going to disturb you just once again, you've helpe me enough, i've updated mu code above, into how it is now, the problem is that it won't display anuhing now.. Can you please check my cde once again, if i've done anything wrong?